# How to Merge the contents of ConfigMaps in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

We have our app specific properties specified in the below files

```
application.properties
application-dev.properties
application-qa.properties
```

While creating a configmap in kubernetes, I wanted to merge the contents into one single file. Is it possible to merge the contents?

I know we can achieve through kustomize. However we are using Helm Charts and we are not using kustomize.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/combineConfigs.md

Answer (score -1):

Place the ConfigMap files inside a folder, and then pass the folder path to the `kubectl` command:

```
kubectl create configmap config-name --from-file=path_to_the_folder
```

Link to follow: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

Comment: The question says "we use helm charts".  That's very much not helm.

Comment: This doesn't merge the files. Each file becomes a key in the configmap, with the value being the file contents.